# How do I initialize static array of pointer in a object

Tags: c++, arrays, object, static

If I for example have a classed called CardHandler and wanna create a static allocated array of pointers that are of a type called Card and have 40 places, how do I write in the h-file and cpp-file?

I have tried something like this:

```
class CardHandler
{
   private:
   Card **arr;
}

CardHandler::CardHandler()
{
    this->arr = new Card*[40];
}
```

But don't think this is the right way? I suspect it's something to do with static.

Comment: An array of pointers should be declared with Card **arr;.

Comment: Why don't you use std::vector?

Comment: @BlueTune not allowed to in this assigment. We are learning about Arrays

Comment: @Paraboloid87 edited it now. But can you answer the question?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean when you say "static"?  What does "static" mean to you in this context?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I mean that I want to create a statically allocated array containing pointers of the card type. Mean fixed size, which you can't expand

Comment: if you need statically allocated array of pointers use `Card* arr[40]`. Note that your are missing the constructor declaration in class `CardHandler`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can create an array of pointers which has a fixed size:

```
class CardHandler
{
private:
    Card* arr[40];
}
```

You'll need to populate the pointers with actual Cards allocated on the heap in the constructor.  Or perhaps better:

```
class CardHandler
{
private:
    Card arr[40];
}
```

That's an array of 40 actual Cards, which you can initialize however you want, but will always be allocated from the moment your constructor is called until after your destructor is called.